Please could we have a new standard flag reason for LLM generated posts
The current best advice to custom flag on discovery of AI Gen posts is to flag with a custom reason. This is for the purposes of enabling moderators to be aware and take appropriate action (e.g. notifying staff enabling them to delete accounts network-wide if appropriate - and to keep track of numbers).
This produces potential uncertainty about what flag-reason should be used as it's not universally known and a workflow bottleneck having to deal with them - and their numbers are only going to increase over time (unless a technical solution can be found long-term, which I doubt).
A new flag reason would speed things up a lot, and still could (if reproduced in sufficient number on a post) result in staff being suitably notified directly.

See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427879/would-a-dedicated-chatgpt-ai-flag-be-a-viable-solution-to-long-response-times-to

One thing to consider is that some sites (SO at least) strongly recommend that you provide evidence in the custom reason box, so preserving that behavior may be worth some thought.

Fair enough, it's a bit of a drudge though, especially when some are so conspicuously awful (one recent user put the AI's introductory comment regarding the questioner's question to them - straight cut n paste). Still, keeps me off the streets as they say. @Anerdw

I don't think AI's 'enough' to do a local deletion, let alone a network wide one.

Persistent offenders do require a certain familiarity and judgement that a casual user may not have. There's one persistent troll in particular that prompted this question - they only just discovered AI. Oh, joy. Their network account gets deleted regularly, it'd just be a lot more convenient to not have to start typing when doing the rounds with a cup of tea in one hand and a mouse in the other. Waste of tea if it goes cold. @JourneymanGeek

As a mod, AFAIK staff doesn't check nor is notified by flags on sites (it's not their job to moderate sites). It's always the mod's responsibility whether they want to escalate it to staff or not.
